# LinkedIn API Integration - 'Not authorized' error and Access to Direct Messaging Threads #Linkedin

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am currently working on integrating the direct messaging functionality using the LinkedIn API. After  reviewing the LinkedIn API documentation, I encountered the following error/response:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: POST /messages",
    "status": 403
}
```

The documentation has mentioned the following:

```
Usage of this API is restricted to approved partners, subject to limitations via API agreement.
```

As shown in the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/messages

I also check the documentation of Messages API, but there is not mentioned anywhere about the read messages API.

So do they even provide APIs to fetch messages from inbox?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to ask LinkedIn about their approval process. Stackoverflow is for programming questions. See also the [tour] and [ask] please